# xlwings - Delete a range of rows

Tags: xlwings

I can't seem to find a way to be able to delete a range of rows starting at row x and going to the bottom of the sheet

For example in VBA code I would do

```
  Rows(CStr(currRow) & ":65536").Select
  Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

where currRow could be anything - i.e I don't necessarily want to delete everything from the sheet

Is there an equivalent in xlwings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an open [issue](https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/issues/80) to take care of that. In the meantime, as usual, you can work around as explained in the [docs](http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/missing_features.html).

In your case, something like the following should do (using v0.9 syntax):

```
import xlwings as xw
from xlwings.constants import DeleteShiftDirection

sht = xw.sheets.active
sht.range(str(currRow) + ':65536').api.Delete(DeleteShiftDirection.xlShiftUp)
```