# How do I delete a row in Excel with xlwings?

Tags: python, automated-tests, xlwings

I know this was answered before ([xlwings - Delete a range of rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38873058/xlwings-delete-a-range-of-rows?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)), but does not work any more....

I'm using python 2.7 with xlwings 0.11.7 edit:(on Mac)

*The answer from above mentioned question:*

```
import xlwings as xw
from xlwings.constants import DeleteShiftDirection
sht = xw.sheets.active
sht.range(str(currRow) + ':65536').api.Delete(DeleteShiftDirection.xlShiftUp)
```

Does anyone know how to delete (not just clearing values) a row or range of row?